# Multiple hardware timers in Linux

Tags: linux, timer, kernel

Problem - There is an intermittent clock drift (of 2 seconds) on my Linux system, so once in a while the kernel timer threads get executed 2 seconds + timeout time

Question - There are multiple hardware clocksources (TSC, HPET, ACPI_PM), is it possible to create kernel timer threads that forcibly uses a secondary clocksource as a fallback, if the primary clocksource drifts..?

Comment: Have you tried just making your system use ntp (a little more often) to keep the time in sync? How long does it take to drift 2s?

Comment: Re: "if the primary clocksource drifts": How will it know that the primary clock-source drifted?

Comment: yes NTP is used and time gets into sync, but even first clockdrift causes my kernel timer-thread to miss a particular HW watchdog. If i can use another HW clock based timer-thread as a backup this could be fixed - is this possible..?

Comment: if you are able to detect drift in kernel mode then can't you use clocksource_register/clocksource_unregister methods inside the existing timer thread. In theory, you dont need to create new thread.

Comment: ntp is the official kernel way to track time. If you run the ntp check often enough, your clock shouldn't drift much. If that's not feasible, you will probably need to rethink your timer strategy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe doesn't sound like clock drift (systematic error) but rather like lost timer interrupts. If you have another piece of hardware that can generate timed interrupts (HPET, RTC, but not TSC), you can make your time-sensitive processing from either the timer or the interrupt handler (or handlers), whichever happens first, you just need to design some kind of synchronization between them.

If you experience genuine clock drift, when the speed of your clock is less than real time, you can try to estimate it and compensate when timers are scheduled. But lost interrupts is a sign of a more serious problem and it makes sense to address the root cause, which may affect your secondary interrupt source as well.